# JavaScript Array Map Function not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have got an issue with the Array.map function not working as I would expect. I have simplified my example below, I just want to get an understanding of where I am going wrong.

So I have the following code below:

```
console.log(this.reportTestData)
let data = this.reportTestData.map((row) => {
    return [ 1 , 2, 3]
});
console.log(data)
return data
```

From the first console.log, this.reportTestData is an array containing 92 objects, the content of each object is irrelevant:

[image]

So from the code, I would expect the map function to run over the array 92 times, and return a new array ( [1,2,3] ) for each element. Leaving me with an array of 92 elements, which each element is a [1,2,3] array. However that is not what I get.

[image]

Instead I am getting an array of 92 elements, but each element is completely empty.

I also tried to return objects from the map function instead:

```
 console.log(this.reportTestData)
 let data = this.reportTestData.map((col) => {
     return { test : 1 }
 });
 console.log(data)
 return data
```

However I still get empty objects returned with no properties:

[image]

Any help that could be offered would be greatly appreciated, as I cannot see where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Please  post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: As mentioned in the answers on this post, that code snippet should work perfectly fine. You should debug your code to find out if the variable "data" is being modified at any later stage in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried for 10 items in an array, and as you may see there are 10-pieces of [1,2,3] ... so map function is working fine, as par I can say.

```js
let reportTestData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
console.log(reportTestData)
let data = reportTestData.map((item) => [ 1 , 2, 3]);
console.log(data)
```

Now trying again with 10-objects in an array:

```js
let reportTestData = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
console.log(reportTestData)
let data = reportTestData.map((item) => [ 1 , 2, 3]);
console.log(data)
```

Again `map` function of `Arrays` works fine, so you need to check what wrong you are doing in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me

```js
const reportTestData = new Array(12).fill(0);
let data1 = reportTestData.map((row) => {
    return [ 1 , 2, 3]
});
console.log(data1)

let data2 = reportTestData.map((row) => {
    return { test : 1 }
});
console.log(data2)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: yeah and mine was first. So anyway the question should be deleted